# How to use variables in brackets?

Tags: python, arrays, class, oop, variables

Here is the part of code:

```
def keisti(self, galune, pakeitimas):

    sk = len(galune)

    if self.word[-sk:] == galune:
        interim = self.word[:-sk]
        interim += pakeitimas

        return interim

    else:

        return None
```

Some of the variables names are in my native language, so don't be surprised.
As you can see - there is variable named `sk` which is an integer.

I want to check if the last `sk` letters of the `self.word` is equal to other variable and then do someting but it just don't work.

I think the problem is in the `[-sk:]` part.

Maybe you know how to do that correctly?

**Edit:**

It seems that the problem actually appears somewhere inside my class and the function itself is working fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class Linksniuoti:

def __init__(self, word):
    self.word = word
    self.vardininkas = ""
    self.kilmininkas = ""
    self.naudininkas = ""
    self.galininkas = ""
    self.inagininkas = ""
    self.vietininkas = ""
    self.sauksmininkas = ""

    if self.word.endswith("as"):
        self.sex = "mas"
        self.type = "vardininkas"
        self.last = self.word[-2:]
        self.fvardininkas()

    if self.word.endswith("o"):
        self.sex = "mas"
        self.type = "kilmininkas"
        self.fkilmininkas()

def keisti(self, galune, pakeitimas):

        sk = len(galune)

        if self.word.endswith(galune):
            interim = self.word[:-sk]
            interim += pakeitimas

            return interim

        else:

            return "no"

def fvardininkas(self):

    if self.last == "as":

        # Kilmininkas
        self.kilmininkas = self.keisti(self.last, "o")

        # Naudininkas
        self.naudininkas = self.keisti(self.last, "ui")

        # Galininkas
        self.galininkas = self.keisti(self.last, "ą")

        # Įnagininkas
        self.inagininkas = self.keisti(self.last, "u")

        # Vietininkas
        self.vietininkas = self.keisti(self.last, "e")

        # Šauksmininkas
        self.sauksmininkas = self.keisti(self.last, "ai")


zodis = Linksniuoti("Mantas")

print zodis.vardininkas
```

Output:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: "it just don't work" -- Can you be more explicit?  Can you provide some inputs that demonstrate it "not working" and explain what you expected to happen?

Comment: `"foobar"[-3:]=="bar"` works fine (evaluates as `True`), so I suspect the problem is with your test values. What values have you tried, and what result did you see, compared to what you expected?

Comment: An easier way: `if self.word.endswith(galune)`

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Let's say **self.word = "abcde"** (I'm not going to provide full class because it's too big.) I want to use function "keisti" like this:
keisti("de", "fg"). The output should be "abcfg".

Comment: gojomo, it works with an integer (like "foobar"[-3:]). It doesn't work with a variable ("foobar"[-sk:]).

Comment: It works with a constant or a variable for me. **Please** make a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @MantasMinioDeksnys Just tried it and it works: `s = "sdfgsdfsd"; f = 4; print (s[-f:])` Prints `dfsd`

Answer (score 1):

So actual problem was that I haven't assigned any value to `self.vardininkas` variable. I'm ashamed of myself.. Thank you anyway!